# How to put a cross X on top of a button?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

On my site [33hotels.com](http://33hotels.com) I am using Buttons, such as provided by Twitter Bootstrap, to indicate hotels' amenities.

What I need is to clearly display that an amenity is absent.
For this, I am already displaying the button in red with text crossed by horizontal line. However, from user testing feedback, this is not enough to deliver the message that the amenity is *absent*. So I need something more clear.

I am thinking of putting a *Large* cross (letter 'X' or an icon) on top of the button, of the size of the button. The cross should be thin as not to obscure the text but still clearly visible.

My questions are:

- How do you put an 'X' on top of a button?
- Any elegant and re-usable way to do it?

Maybe define a web component or Angular directive "crossed" that can be attached to an HTML Element?

EDIT. Made my question more clear - I need to put a large X of the size of the button.

EDIT 2: Here is  [the ugly version of what I'm trying to achieve](http://jsbin.com/losalu/1/edit). However, apart from being ugly, it fails to make the text crossed readable. So perhaps I should use a thinner version of 'X'?

EDIT 3: Here is as good as I could get, not too pretty :(
http://cl.ly/image/1H1p0n2V2200

Comment: Why not disable the button instead? Make it un-clickable and grayed-out?

Comment: @Ideogram The button should be clickable with the purpose to remove that user preference. Even if not, that would still not serve the purpose. A disabled button carries the message that you can't click on it. What I need is to deliver the message that the amenity displayed by the button is absent.

Comment: Having looked at your site I'd suggest (and it may be worth checking over at [ui.se]) that your problem is that the red enhances the buttons' visibility, which seems directly opposite to your need. I'd second the use of the `disabled` attribute to reduce its appearance of interactivity. Though why you're showing buttons at all that should have no function confuses me. With regards to your last comment, it would be worth adding that clarification to the question (since it clearly confused both myself and Ideogram).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for your suggestions, checking with UX is good one! The reason it is displayed because it displays customer's preference requested. If I can't satisfy all preferences, instead of showing empty list, I rather show results that partially satisfy them. So I have to make it clear that some of requested amenities are missed.

Comment: Indeed, checking with the UX list seems like a good idea. I think it's very good that the PO (Dmitiri) is incorporating user feedback!(LIKE!) 

May I suggest using a 'exit sign', an 'X', a trashcan, an eraser (etc...) glyphicon *appended* to the text on the button, f.e. 

[  balcony   ×  ]"?

Answer (score 3):

This is How you do it >> [Close button](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq3RS/4/)

[image]

> **html**

---

```
<button class="btn btn-default">End Tour<div class="closebox">X</div>
```

> **css**

---

```
button {
    position:relative;
}
.closebox {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.5;
    top:-30px;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    font-size:5em;
}
```

Comment: I see there an 'X' at the corner of my modal dialogue. Which looks like its purpose to close the dialogue. What I need is a large 'X' placed on top of the button, covering the button. Whose purpose is to show visually that the property displayed by the button is absent.

Comment: Also `5px` looks like a "magic number". Can be a problem to make it re-usable for both large and small buttons.

Comment: Does my question EDIT clarify it?

Comment: Any button on the site! Ideally adding a class "crossed" or Angular directive!

Comment: Almost - the X should stay inside the button, also I am trying to avoid "magic" numbers inside CSS declarations to make it reusable for buttons of various size.

Comment: My buttons have different sizes, so I can't use hard-coded settings, need to adapt for each button, which is why I look for dynamic solution, suitable for buttons of any length.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, following code will work for you

```
<div class="btn push ng-binding btn-default" 
ng-class="feature.selected ? 'btn-primary': 'btn-default'" 
ng-mousedown="toggleFeature(feature, category, $event)" 
ng-bind="feature.name"> 
    <span style="position: relative;top: -9px;float: right;right: -9px;">×</span>
    Courtyard
</div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a large 'X' covering the whole button and has hard-coded "magic" number `9` - sort of thing I am trying to avoid.

Comment: this is not a large `x` and it is just small `x` in the right top of the button. check your button `Courtyard` and update the html using page inspector, you will see the `x` in right in place. 9 is depends on the padding of the button.

Comment: I need the X to be the size of the button (which depends on the button), sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using css dynamic content via `content:"X"` and placing the style on your `button` element utilizing pseudo-elements for placing the content....
my example is entirely too specific with sizes and positioning: i just wanted to show you how you could do it:
http://jsbin.com/hijaw/1/

Comment: Thanks, pseudo-elements are indeed good for this purpose but I still don't see how to stretch the X to look nice on top of the button.

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap 3, you can do something like below

```
<button type="button" class="close">Close
    <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px">&times;</span>
</button>
```

**EDIT**

another example with font-aswesome

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" >
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Settings
 </button>
```

**EDIT 2**

to change the size

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" >
    <i class="fa fa-times" style="font-size: 1em"></i> Settings
 </button>
```

you can increase font size using style on  tag

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it is not meant for the modal popup, but for the buttons. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Answer is for buttons only

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't seem to put X to cover the button. Could you show in a jsbin? Thanks!

Comment: Any explanation why `aria-hidden` is needed?

Comment: It does not make &times; of the size of the button

Comment: also added example with `font awesome`

Comment: I don't know how to change font size of the icon depending on the (horizontal) size of the button. This is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use font-awesome or glyphicon to represent when an amenity is absent or not (ok or cross icon + amenity name). Very easy to use and you will avoid to use images or dirty CSS. check Bootstrap 3 examples in:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: Can I stretch that icon to cover the button?